# AlertDialog makes my released version of my app crash

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to display a dialog to the user and this is my code (running in MainActivity)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("title");
    builder.setMessage("Test Message");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

My app theme is inherited from Theme.MaterialComponents and this is MyDialogTheme:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">#222222</item>
    <item name="android:text">#ccffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ccffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

The released APK of my app works fine on most of the devices (I have tested it on Samsung A22, S10+, A50 and Xiaomi note 8) but it crashes on LG-G4 with android 6.0

Even it works fine on LG-G4 in debug mode! but when I install the released apk on it, it crashes! when I connect LG device to computer with cable, Android studio display the crash reason as follows:

```
2022-04-15 00:37:07.055 12860-12860/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ir.kolbe.fale_ghahve, PID: 12860
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.kolbe.fale_ghahve/ir.kolbe.fale_ghahve.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.DialogTitle
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.DialogTitle
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at g.k.u()
```

Here you can download app [proguard mapping file](http://dl.farhadkargaran.ir/tmp/mapping.zip)

I know the problem is setting theme on AlertDialog because when I remove the theme it works fine on LG-g4 on both debug mode and released APK!

Any Idea on how to solve this issue to work on all devices? (by the way I have tried with minifyEnabled true and false, but the result is the same)

Comment: you forgot to include whole crash stacktrace

Comment: Are you enabling the ProGuard ?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI I have tried with both state, minifyEnabled true and false. but the same result

Comment: Care to attach your proguard mapping file (in `build/generated/output/…`)? I need to know what’s the original name of class`g.k` and its function `u`

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel I attached mapping files to my post

Comment: In your `release` build type, try to use default mapping file `proguard-android` instead `proguard-android-optimize`, then let's see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel unfortunately the problem persist

Comment: All libs updated to their latest?